# Renaming multiple files with rename

Tags: shell, shell-script, rename

I need to rename files in batch--the other questions I browsed don't exactly address my problem. The names of my files are generated non-deterministically, so I can't predict what they will be named. I do know that they will start with `NORMAL` and end with `-lib*`. I'd like to replace everything in between with some string `X`. For example,

```
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.concordant
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.deletion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.divergent
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.inversion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib1.translocation
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.concordant
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.deletion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.divergent
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.insertion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.inversion
|   |   |-- NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.translocation
```

So it will probably be of the form `rename "s/something/X/"`, but I don't know what that something should be, as I don't know how to use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are lucky enough to have `rename` available, then the following should be sufficient:

```
rename 's/(NORMAL).*(-lib)/$1X$2/' *
```

Answer (score 2):

The useful Perl powered `rename` isn't always available on all distros. For example, Fedora and CentOS (and presumably RedHat) use a basic `rename` utility that does basic search and replace and nothing much else.

If you're unfortunate enough to be using one of those, then something like the following may help:

```
for oldname in *; do
    newname=$(echo "$oldname" | sed -e 's/\(NORMAL\).*\(-lib.*\)/\1X\2/')
    mv "$oldname" "$newname"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two unrelated programs called `rename`. The one found on Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, …) is a Perl script, and its first argument is a Perl expression that transforms the old name into the new name. With that script, you can do

```
rename 's/.*-lib/NORMAL_X-lib/' NORMAL_*-lib*
```

The [`s` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer) performs a [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) replacement. There are oodles of regular expression tutorials on the web, e.g. [1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). `.*-lib` matches the string up to the last occurrence of `-lib` (`.*` matches any string), so `s/.*-lib/NORMAL_X-lib/` replaces the `NORMAL_blahblah-lib` part by `NORMAL_X-lib`.

If you have a Linux distribution that isn't derived from Debian, then the `rename` utility is one that is suitable for almost no practical task. You can use a shell loop instead.

```
for x in NORMAL_*-lib*; do
  mv "$x" "NORMAL_X-lib${x##*-lib}"
done
```

`${x##*-lib}` is the value of the variable `x` minus the part up to the last occurrence of `-lib`. This is standard [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) syntax.

This task is easiest in zsh, with its [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function. Put `autoload -U zmv` in your `.zshrc` (or run it on the command line for a once-off), then run

```
zmv 'NORMAL_*-(lib*)' 'NORMAL_X-$1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using *lookarounds*, like `(?<=NORMAL).*?(?=-lib)` i.e.

```
$ rename -v -n -- 's/(?<=NORMAL).*?(?=-lib)/X/' *
NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.insertion renamed as NORMALX-lib4.insertion
NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.inversion renamed as NORMALX-lib4.inversion
NORMAL_H_LS-A7-A0CE-10A-01D-A017-09-lib4.translation renamed as NORMALX-lib4.translation
```