# How to rename multiple files by inserting numbers

Tags: rename

I have a list of files like the following:

```
pairs10_10.mp3
pairs10_11.mp3
pairs10_12.mp3
pairs10_13.mp3
pairs10_14.mp3
pairs10_15.mp3
pairs10_16.mp3
pairs10_17.mp3
pairs10_18.mp3
pairs10_19.mp3
pairs10_1.mp3
pairs10_2.mp3
pairs10_3.mp3
pairs10_4.mp3
pairs10_5.mp3
pairs10_6.mp3
pairs10_7.mp3
pairs10_8.mp3
pairs10_9.mp3
pairs1_10.mp3
```

I would like to get something like the following so that when they are later sorted they would be in the correct order:

```
pairs10_10.mp3
pairs10_11.mp3
pairs10_12.mp3
pairs10_13.mp3
pairs10_14.mp3
pairs10_15.mp3
pairs10_16.mp3
pairs10_17.mp3
pairs10_18.mp3
pairs10_19.mp3
pairs10_01.mp3
pairs10_02.mp3
pairs10_03.mp3
pairs10_04.mp3
pairs10_05.mp3
pairs10_06.mp3
pairs10_07.mp3
pairs10_08.mp3
pairs10_09.mp3
pairs01_10.mp3
```

I just learned about the `rename` command but I don't know how to do this type of rename.

Comment: Don't rename them use the [sort command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort).  Use the `-n` option.

Comment: @eyoung100 That's a good idea too.

Comment: Using bash: `for f in $(find . -name "pairs?_10.mp3"); do mv "$f" "${f%?_10.mp3}0${f#./pairs}" ; done;`

Comment: This is just a partial list. The pattern is "pairs" + (1 or 2 digit number) + "_" + (1 or 2 digit number) + ".mp3"

Comment: You have not said anything about how to choose 0 or 1 or 2 when renaming. You then need to add these rules in your question

Answer (score 2):

With the Perl `rename` command:

```
rename 's/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)/sprintf("%02d_%02d",$1,$2)/e' *.mp3
```

The `e` modifier to the [`s` substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer) means that the replacement is a Perl expression rather than an interpolated string. The format `%02d` for the function [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) formats an integer with exactly two digits, adding leading zeroes as necessary.

---

Alternatively, use zsh and its [`numeric_glob_sort`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NUMERIC_005fGLOB_005fSORT) option. However that only applies when zsh is doing the globbing (as in `play pairs*.mp3`).

Answer (score 1):

POSIX:

`for f in *;do x=${f#pairs};y=${f#*_};mv $f pairs_$(printf %02d_%02d ${x%_*} ${y%.mp3}).mp3;done`

zsh:

`autoload zmv;zmv 'pairs(*)_(*).mp3' 'pairs${(l:2::0:)1}_${(l:2::0:)2}.mp3'`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a multi-step process with the rename command. It could probably be simplified:

```
rename 's/(pairs)([0-9])_/$1Z$2_/' *.mp3
rename 's/(_)([0-9])\./$1Z$2\./' *.mp3
rename 's/Z/0/' *.mp3
rename 's/Z/0/' *.mp3
```

(The $1 and $2 refer to the parentheses in the first part)

("Z" is just a place holder because "0" gets mixed up with "$1")

idea from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147912/86521